# Hibernate Query - can't seem to compare all sets of data?

Tags: hibernate

Here is my database structure:

```
    Foo: //foo class
       Set<Students> students;
       Set<Teachers> teachers;
    //students
    Students:
       Int id;
       String name;
    //teachers
    Teachers:
       Int id;
       String name;


    Criteria criteria = sess.createCriteria(Foo.class ,"foo").
                             createAlias("students", "student").
                             createAlias("teachers","teacher");

    //create and statement for the student id

    Conjunction andStudent = Restriction.conjunction();
    for (Student student : currentFoo.students) {
        andStudent.add(Restrictions.eq("student.id", student.id));
    }
```

Basically i want to create a hibernate query where given a list of Foo I want to find Foos that matches all the students AND teachers that are in the Foo I am comparing to. So if currentFoo has Student ID 1,3 and Teacher ID 2,4 I want the query to return Foos that contain BOTH Student ID 1,3 and Teacher ID 2,4 and whatever else it might contain.

After i run the query (taking care of unique results and removing the currentFoo result) i get 0 results...

I did remove one of the rows of data from currentFoo for students from 2 rows of id 1,2 to one row of 1 and i got results - so it seems to me one part of the problem is the 2nd row of student isnt being compared or read in during the query? Can someone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use the `eq` `Criterion` in this case.  The `in` `Criterion` is what you need.  Replace your loop with one that builds a collection of student IDs, and then you can use a single (un-looped) restriction:

```
andStudent.add(Restrictions.in("student.id", collectionOfStudentIds));
```

You may even be able to simply do

```
andStudent.add(Restrictions.in("student", collectionOfStudents));
```

but I haven't used this in a while, so I forget if that works.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I did use Restrictions.in before but what it does is it returns Foo if there's ANY id match. For example if Foo has IDs 1,3 and i am comparing to a Foo with student id 1,4,5 i will get that included in the result even though it is not supposed to be...

Comment: That's why you use the conjunction. You want logic like "studentA in currentFoo AND studentB in currentFoo AND teacherX in currentFoo AND teacherY in currentFoo"

Comment: And you can add extra criteria like "AND count of students = 2 AND count of teachers =2" to get the last bit of required logic